# Jquery UI Tabs Floating Divs in tab panel

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I am having trouble trying to get a jquery ui tab panel's height to grow with floating divs within the panel.
the divs have specific data returning to these divs and I need them to float left and right to save ui real estate.
Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, this is a well-known css issue. A discussion is here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

To summarize the article, any `<divs>` that you wish to function as both a tab pane and a float container should have these styles added to them either in your `<style>` or css `<link>` files:

```
overflow: auto;
width: 100%
```

This isn't a bug. It's intentional. The floating div literally lifts out of the container, and the container will not be aware of the floating div. At least, that was the goal.

You should do a search on here for "clearing floats" or other related css rules, because using the above will cause issues with certain browsers (in short: 'take care to test this, all the same').