# Problems in positioning div and image in Jquery UI Tabs Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs, jquery-widgets

I have downloaded Jquery UI Tabs Widget from

> http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

And everything works perfect, when I use the next code:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1">
      <div id="red_div"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2">
    <img src="img_path_here.jpg" />
    Image Test
  </div>
  <div id="tab3">
        Tab 3
  </div>
  <div id="tab4">
    Tab 4
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(function() {
                  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
                });
            });
</script>
```

CSS for red_div:

```
#red_div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

But when I add align attribute for the image, like

```
<img src="img_path_here.jpg" align="left" />
```

or when I add float attribute for div#red_div

```
#red_div {
    ...
    float: left;
}
```

I have problems with positioning. They are not in the place, they are supposed to be. They cross the bottom line. The pictures will describe this better.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/efFnK.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLWJu.jpg
```

How can I get rid of this problem, if I really need to use float for div and align for image? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I have posted this problem on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q6F7r/

Comment: try setting overflow:auto; and can you make jsfiddle of it ?

Comment: It's a little hard to say, but floating a div makes it lose the property of really taking the space of the container. It will not fill it.Change it to relative and do not float it

Comment: I have posted the code on JSFiddle. The address is http://jsfiddle.net/q6F7r/

Comment: did you try taking out the float for div#red. That already works a wonder. It allows the div red to stay in the tab. Change it yourself on fiddle and you can see the result.

Comment: @Daniel Yes. I wrote that it works correct without float at the beginning. But I need the "float:left", because I need to place text to the right from the div#red. And div#red will become a map in future! :)

Comment: I have found solution for div. <div id="red_div"></div>Text for the first tab<div style="clear:both"></div> It's far from perfect, but works fine...

Comment: Thanks .. I have been playing too. Made some changes in the sylesheet and setup of your image. Maybe this gets you further: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/q6F7r/2/

Comment: @daniel Thanks for help. But image in background doen't look appropriate solution for me. Because images will be taken automatically from db. Still don't have solution for "align" image.

Comment: I did see another thing in the API documentation about heightStyle auto, causing all tabs to be as high as the highest one: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-heightStyle
As far as the images.They are inline elements. I can't get that to work. Just a quick workaround could be preloading, reading the size and then place it in the div with jquery .css(). I know that sounds dirty. I would be curious to see what solution comes out. Can't help you otherwise. Good luck and cheers :)

Comment: The only one solution I could find for now is to make img a block element and add "clear:both" after it. I am pretty sure, this is not the best idea, but I don't see another solutions for this moment. But it still looks nice. I have posted the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/8YcYn/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166273/jquery-ui-tabs-floating-divs-in-tab-panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding float (and width) to the "main div".

```
.ui-tabs {float:left; width:100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q6F7r/6/

Comment: I had to use ui-tabs-nav and modify the class using a jQuery selector and the css() method in my .ready function.